# Did I make a simple mistake with my first binary search technique?

Tags: java, arrays, random, foreach, binary-search

I've created an array to generate 10 random numbers between 1-100, sorted them with a for loop (supposed to use the "enhanced for loop"). The last thing left besides making my for loop enhanced is to "enter one value, search array using **binary search technique** to determine if value is present or not and output that. Do you see what is wrong? Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

class lab4point2 //lab4.2 part 1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = new int[10]; //array of 10 numbers created.
        Random rand = new Random(); //random class created called rand.

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < array.length; cnt++) { //for loop to generate
            array[cnt] = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;     // the 10 numbers randomly 1-100
        }
        Arrays.sort(array); //sorted
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));// prints the 10 numbers to screen

        System.out.print("Enter a value to see if it is present. ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = scanner.nextint();

        boolean binarySearch(array, 0, 99, value);
        int size = 100;
        int low = 0;
        int high = size - 1;

        while (high >= low) {
            int middle = (low + high) / 2;
            if (data[middle] == value) {
                System.out.print("Value is present ");
                return true;
            }
            if (data[middle] < value) {
                low = middle + 1;
            }
            if (data[middle] > value) {
                high = middle - 1;
            }
       }
       System.out.print("Value is not present. ");
       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I should have mentioned what errors they are, thanks. Here they are. 24: error: ';' expected
boolean binarySearch(array, 0, 99, value);
                    ^
24: error: not a statement
boolean binarySearch(array, 0, 99, value);
                     ^
24: error: ';' expected
boolean binarySearch(array, 0, 99, value);
                          ^
24: error: not a statement
boolean binarySearch(array, 0, 99, value);
                                   ^
24: error: ';' expected
boolean binarySearch(array, 0, 99, value);
                                        ^
5 errors

Comment: ohh I didn't prototype it?

Comment: I tried to reformat your code so I could read it and removed some syntax errors. I'll add an answer that makes it clearer how it should read.

Comment: If the problem is syntax errors and you removed them, then this seems like a bad edit.

Comment: @WillieWheeler I agree. I thought it was a poor cut and paste - it wasn't until the comment clarifying what the error was that I realised syntax was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your code. It should look more like the following:

```
class SearchArray {
    private final int[] array = new int[10];
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public SearchArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
        }
        Arrays.sort(array);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(array);
    }

    public boolean contains(int value) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = array.length - 1;

        while (high >= low) {
            int middle = (low + high) / 2;
            if (array[middle] == value) {
                return true;
            }
            if (array[middle] < value) {
                low = middle + 1;
            }
            if (array[middle] > value) {
                high = middle - 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }          

class lab4point2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SearchArray array = new SearchArray();
        System.out.println(array.toString());

        System.out.print("Enter a value to see if it is present. ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = scanner.nextint();
        if (array.contains(value)) {
            System.out.print("Value is present. ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Value is not present. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir! I'm studying the changes you've made for me and have a couple questions on them for  the purpose of comprehension/clarification as I'm a college student, if you don't mind! I can see that SearchArray is the name of a class and the constructor, that is clear. 1. Is the variable array an array or an object? and contains() is an independent function? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes I moved your binary search method to a new class which makes more sense than having it in the same class as `main` (that's generally bad practice). I also renamed it to `contains` to match it's function. In Java arrays are really just objects under the covers.

Comment: You're very generous. In main, there is this line. SearchArray array = new SearchArray();  Is this object the array that I already created, or is it a new object with the same name as the array? I'm going to try to make it a for each loop now and will post if I somehow can't manage. Thanks!

Comment: Still getting a few errors. lab4point2.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            if (array[middle] == value) {
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: class SearchArray
lab4point2.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            if (array[middle] < value) {
                                ^

Comment: I shouldn't have used the same variable name for the `SearchArray` object - I realise that confused you. Also forgot to pass value into the method! changed now.

Comment: Hey no problem. It was good trouble shooting practice for me, and after staring at the erros for a while I realized the problem. How contains() didn't have a parameter, but was passed one. Thanks!

Comment: I'm so happy I just keep clicking run and watching it execute like a mad man ;)